# Extract data using Regular Expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex

In C#, how can I extract the info from this string:

```
http://www.example.com/images/this-is-the-url-1234-12-filename.jpg
```

with Regular expression, so that I can get the following data:

```
/1234/12/filename.jpg
```

The above is just an example of the pattern of the URL. The following are a few more examples:

```
http://www.example1.com/images/this-is-something-else-5555-10-anotherfilename.jpg
```

Should return:

```
/5555/10/anotherfilename.jpg
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Post your image directly

Comment: @ADITYA I think the purpose of the links are not the images, they are just examples of input data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the two example URLs provided, you can extract the needed information with this pattern:

```
string pattern = @"-(\d+\-\d+\-[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+)";
```

Using the following code will split the URL into 2 parts, where the desired string is in the second sub string:

```
string input = "http://www.example.com/images/this-is-the-url-1234-12-filename.jpg";
string pattern = @"-(\d+\-\d+\-[a-zA-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]+)";           

string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
```

So `substrings[1]` will be `1234-12-filename.jpg`. Then you only need to replace "-" with "/", like this for example:

```
var newString = "/" + substrings[1].Replace("-", "/")
```

and you should get the desired result.

**NOTE:** This will only work if all URLs you want to change have the following pattern in the end:

"*-number-number-filename.extension*"

and also this pattern does not occur anywhere else in the URL.